# Accessing FlowFile content in NIFI PutS3Object Processor

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I am new to NIFI and want to push data from Kafka to an S3 bucket. I am using the `PutS3Object` processor and can push data to S3 if I hard code the Bucket value as mphdf/orderEvent, but I want to specify the buckets based on a field in the content of the FlowFile, which is in Json. So, if the Json content is this `{"menu": {"type": "file","value": "File"}}`, can I have the value for the Bucket property as as `mphdf/$.menu.type`? I have tried to do this and get the error below. I want to know if there is a way to access the FlowFile content with the PutS3Object processor and make Bucket names configurable or will I have to build my own processor?

```
ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10]
o.a.nifi.processors.aws.s3.PutS3Object
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The XML you
provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our
published schema (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
MalformedXML; Request ID: 77DF07828CBA0E5F)
```

[image: PutS3Object Nifi Processor]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is use an `EvaluateJSONPath` processor, which evaluates arbitrary JSONPath expressions against the JSON content and extracts the results to flowfile attributes. You can then reference the flowfile attribute using NiFi Expression Language in the `PutS3Object` configuration (see your first property **Object Key** which references `${filename}`). In this way, you would evaluate `$.menu.type` and store it into an attribute **menuType** in the `EvaluateJSONPath` processor, then in `PutS3Object` you would have **Bucket** be `mphdf/${menuType}`.

You might have to play around with it a bit but off the top of my head I think that should work.